# AngularJS, multiple draggable items causes 'jump' on initial move

Tags: javascript, html, dom, angularjs, coffeescript

I am using the example code located on the AngularJS main site. When I move the first draggable object, all is well. As soon as I begin dragging a second object, the second object 'jumps' exactly the distance which the first object was moved.

Initially I thought the fix would be as simple as resetting the variables. Unfortunately, all of my attempts have caused 'indentation errors'.

```
# Angular Drag Components RE-uses vars from previous drag, bugging out the dragging
angular.module("aehalo", []).directive "draggable", ($document) ->
  startX = 0
  startY = 0
  x = 0
  y = 0
  (scope, element, attr) ->
    mousemove = (event) ->
      y = event.screenY - startY
      x = event.screenX - startX
      element.css
        top: y + "px"
        left: x + "px"

    mouseup = ->
      $document.unbind "mousemove", mousemove
      $document.unbind "mouseup", mouseup
    element.css
      position: "relative"
      border: "1px solid red"
      backgroundColor: "lightgrey"
      cursor: "pointer"
    element.bind "mousedown", (event) ->
      startX = event.screenX - x
      startY = event.screenY - y
      $document.bind "mousemove", mousemove
      $document.bind "mouseup", mouseup
```

Comment: Indentation errors sound like an issue with coffeescript, not angular. Regarding your issue - the right place to reset the x/y values would appear to be the mousedown event, prior to anything else.

Comment: So adding "x = 0" and "y = 0" in the said location still causes an indentation error. And when I replace the x and the y directly with 0's, then the object moves back to its original location before any movement.

Comment: Sounds to me more like a shared scope issue. Are you isolating scope on the directive? The code above doesn't appear to.

Comment: Do you have a reference I can see for isolating the scope as a directive? The answer below has helped me, but I have been indulging on angular so any source you can provide will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like resetting `x` and `y` in the `mousedown` even would fix it:

```
    element.bind "mousedown", (event) ->
      x = 0
      y = 0
      startX = event.screenX - x
      startY = event.screenY - y
      $document.bind "mousemove", mousemove
      $document.bind "mouseup", mouseup
```

If you're still getting indentation errors, make sure you aren't mixing tabs and spaces in your indentation.