# AngularJS toggling ngShow for all entries

Tags: javascript, angularjs, coffeescript, angularjs-scope

For each 'entry in entries', I have a button the toggles ng-show to true and displays details about the entry. Currently, this code toggles every entry to ng-show=true. I want each button to only toggle the details for the entry it is located in.

My View:

```
<h1>Listing Projects</h1>
<ul class="unstyled">
    <li ng-repeat="entry in entries" ng-init="entryClass=isClass(entry.isProject)">
        <ul class="unstyled">
            <li>
                <div class="alert" ng-class="entryClass">
                    <h3>{{entry.title}}</h3>
                    <button ng-click="toggleShow()">Details</button>
                    <div style="background-color:#000000; min-width:100px; min-height:100px;" ng-show="showThis">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

The AngularJS:

```
app = angular.module("Resume", ["ngResource"])

app.factory "Entry", ["$resource", ($resource) ->
  $resource("/entries")
]

@EntryCtrl = ["$scope", "Entry", ($scope, Entry) ->
  $scope.entries = Entry.query()
  $scope.showThis = false

  $scope.isClass = (isProject) ->
    if isProject == true
      $scope.myVar = "project alert-info"
    else
      $scope.myVar = "tech alert-success"


  $scope.toggleShow = ->
    if $scope.showThis == false
      $scope.showThis = true
    else
      $scope.showThis = false
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pass the entry to your function:

```js
$scope.toggleShow = (entry) ->
    entry.showThis = !entry.showThis
```

```html
<button ng-click="toggleShow(entry)">Details</button>
<div ng-show="entry.showThis">stuff here</div>
```

---

Alternatively, you *could* just handle the whole thing in the markup:

```html
<button ng-click="entry.showThis = !entry.showThis">Details</button>
<div ng-show="entry.showThis">stuff here</div>
```

---

*More alternatively* you could use `$index` and a separate object:

```
$scope.showEntry = {}

$scope.toggleShow = (index) ->
    $scope.showEntry[index] = !$scope.showEntry[index]
```

```html
<button ng-click="toggleShow($index)">Details</button>
<div ng-show="showEntry[$index]">stuff here</div>
```

So there's a few options for you. Happy coding.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I went with the second option since it requires the least amount of code. Perhaps you can help me with my other angular question. Thanks! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15227715/angularjs-multiple-draggable-items-causes-jump-on-initial-move

Answer (score 1):

Your $scope.showThis variable serves as a reference for all your entries. Hence, when you change it for one entry, all other entries get changed as well.

Your `isClass` function is also not doing much because you're not actually using the `myVar` anywhere. That 'myVar' variable tells me that you were trying to follow the [ng-class docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angClass) but I'm afraid you went off track a bit with it.

This is what you probably wanted your HTML to be like:

```
<h1>Listing Projects</h1>
<ul class="unstyled">
  <li ng-repeat="entry in entries">
    <ul class="unstyled">
      <li>
       <div class="alert" ng-class="{true: 'project alert-info', false: 'tech alert-success'}[entry.isProject]">
          <h3>{{entry.title}}</h3>
          <button ng-click="toggleShow($index)">Details</button>
          <div style="background-color:#000000; min-width:100px; min-height:100px;" ng-show="shouldShow($index)">
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

and this is the matching controller for the HTML above:

```
app.controller('AppController',
  [
    '$scope',
    function($scope) {
      $scope.entries = [
        {isProject: false, title: 'Entry1'}, 
        {isProject: true, title: 'Entry2'}
      ];
      var visible = [];

      $scope.toggleShow = function(index){
        position = visible.indexOf(index);
        if(position===-1) {
          visible.push(index);
          return;
        }
        visible.splice(position, 1);
      };

      $scope.shouldShow = function(index){
        return visible.indexOf(index) != -1;
      };

    }
  ]
);
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/4uuFACyFt1ShEfeOnk4s)